# Error Bootstrap Year Calendar

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap, plugin

Estoy intentando utilizar el Bootstrap Year Calendar, para crear un calendario anual, haciéndolo igual que en su web. Pero cuando o inicializo, me aparecen solo los 4 primeros meses, y en columna, es decir, sólo un mes por fila como en esta imagen:

[image: Mi calendario]

A continuación os dejo mi código, a ver si no he puesto algo bien, soy bastante inexperto en este tema:

```html
<?php
if (strpos(getcwd(), 'apen_files') !== false) {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd());
} else {
 define('_PS_ADMIN_DIR_', getcwd().'/includes/apen_files/');
}
require (_PS_ADMIN_DIR_."/config.php"); 

?>
<head>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="css/bootstrap-year-calendar.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ZMP7rVo3mIykV+2+9J3UJ46jBk0WLaUAdn689aCwoqbBJiSnjAK/l8WvCWPIPm49" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-smHYKdLADwkXOn1EmN1qk/HfnUcbVRZyYmZ4qpPea6sjB/pTJ0euyQp0Mk8ck+5T" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div data-provide="calendar"></div>
</body>
<script>$(function() {
    $('#calendar').calendar();
});</script>
```

Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Lo he solucionado poniendo un float: left; pero algunos años me salen desordenados, por ejemplo en 2019 me sale mayo a la parte derecha dejando todo un hueco debajo de Enero, Febrero...no sé como solucionar eso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Según el código que as enseñado tienes varios errores:

1. En la estructura del html te falta el Doctype y el tag `<html>`
2. El script javascript del final de la página no esta dentro del body.
3. El div donde tiene que cargar, le falta el ID que hace referencia al scrip: `<div id="calendar" data-provide="calendar"></div>`

Aparte de lo de antes, he visto que el chico que a creado el código
Creo que es esta pagina: http://www.bootstrap-year-calendar.com/ no esta utilizando la misma version de bootstrap que tu.

Tu has cargado la version 4.1.1 y el esta utilizando la version v3.3.5

Comment: Gracias por tu ayuda, pero me sigue funcionando igual, me salen los meses de uno en uno...todos en una columna

Comment: Para que te funcione con flex tendrás que hacer:

.months-container {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.calendar .month-container {
    flex-basis: 19.7%;
}

la propiedad flex-basis tendrás que ir adaptandola con media queries y por ultimo tendrás que mirar como se llama la clase del modal para que aparezca por encima del contenido. Espero que te sirva para poder seguir al menos

Comment: Por fiiiiiin! Ahora si que me ha servido! Muchas gracias @Daniel Bardaji Torres , por cierto, lo último que has escrito no se a que te refieres, me sale todo correctamente.

Comment: Me alegro! Marca como solucionado esta respuesta y así se cerrara la pregunta en StackOverflow! Un placer haberte ayudado!

Answer (score 0):

A mi me funciona importando en este orden

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-year-calendar.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' href="css/bootstrap-year-calendar.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Comment: No me funciona igual...